# OpenCV C++ Convert Byte array to Mat

Tags: opencv

How can I convert byte array  to Mat which is received from socket ?.

My client application will send color image data like this

```
Mat frame; //colour image
int imgSize = frame.total()*frame.elemSize();
int bytes = send(clientSock, frame.data, imgSize, 0));//write to the socket
```

And the server will receives the data like

```
    char sockData[imgSize];
    Mat img;
    for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += bytes) {
        bytes = recv(connectSock, sockData +i, imgSize  - i, 0));
    }

   // Write to mat
    for (int i = 0;  i < img.rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
         (img.row(i)).col(j) = (uchar)sockData[((img.cols)*i)+j];
       }
     }
```

I am getting distorted image at the receiver. Is there any problem in my code ?
Thanks in advance.......

Comment: why sockData is an array of char and not uchar?

Comment: why do you not use the cv::Mat::at<T>(x,y) method? remember that x is the column from left to right and y is the row from top to bottom

Comment: if the image is in color -> CV_8UC3 you have 3 channel of 8 bit for each pixels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have colour image you may read it in a math with 3 channels of uchar so change this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < img.rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
     (img.row(i)).col(j) = (uchar)sockData[((img.cols)*i)+j];
   }
 }
```

with this:

```
int baseIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < img.rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
     img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(sockData[baseIndex + 0],
                                        sockData[baseIndex + 1],
                                        sockData[baseIndex + 2]);
     baseIndex = baseIndex + 3;
   }
 }
```

Maybe this should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply....I tested your code but still distorted image and I found the reason the sockData pointer is increasing like (0,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,4)....on for loop and it should be like (0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),...Any way you give me the tips. I just solved that issue, I will post that below...

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn't look at how the index was incremented, just copy and paste, you're right!

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work?

```
cv::Mat frame(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC3, sockData);
```

Just replace CV_8UC3 with the correct image format:

```
CV_<bit-depth>{U|S|F}C(<number_of_channels>)
```

see https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

---

Edit:  There is a 5th additional field which can be useful.  The number of bytes per row (in case there are a few padding bytes).  In working with V4L2 today, I successfully used this cv::Mat constructor:

```
v4l2_format camera_format = ...; // see https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/vidioc-g-fmt.html#description
cv::Mat mat(camera_format.fmt.pix.height,
            camera_format.fmt.pix.width,
            CV_8UC3,
            raw_data_ptr,
            camera_format.fmt.pix.bytesperline);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using  below code.

```
int ptr=0;

 for (int i = 0;  i < img.rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) { 

        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(sockData[ptr+0],sockData[ptr+1],sockData[ptr+2]);
        ptr=ptr+3;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Michele answer, one can also use the MatIterator to solve this.

```
cv::Mat m;
m.create(10, 10, CV_32FC3);

// This is the socket data.
float *array = (float *)malloc( 3*sizeof(float)*10*10 );

cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3f> it = m.begin<cv::Vec3f>();
for (unsigned i = 0; it != m.end<cv::Vec3f>(); it++ ) {
    for ( unsigned j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        (*it)[j] = *(array + i );
        i++;
    }
}

Now you have a float cv::Mat. In case of 8 bit, simply change float to uchar and Vec3f to Vec3b and CV_32FC3 to CV_8UC3
```